# Missing Keyword Error using Inner join in SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am new to SQL and thus facing some problems in enhancing a SQL query.

There are two tables basically: one is ef_dat_app_ef_link and the other is ef_dat_lspd_machine_type_model

Here is the query I am talking about. I have added an inner join in the 10th line which is the base of all problems.

```
select country_isocode as country,
language_isocode as language, model_number,
machine_type_model_name model_name,machine_type_group_id,
machine_type_model_id, product_type_name product_type,
machine_type_model_id_to,filenet_link 
from ef_dat_lspd_machine_type_model,
cross join ef_dim_lspd_country_language
left join ef_dat_lspd_model_country 
using (machine_type_model_id, country_isocode)
inner join ef_dat_app_ef_link on  (ef_dat_lspd_machine_type_model.lpmd_revenue_pid = ef_dat_app_ef_link.ef_product_revenue_pid)
where (ef_dat_app_ef_link.country_isocode='US' or ef_dat_app_ef_link.country_isocode='CA') and ef_dat_app_ef_link.language_isocode='en'
join ef_dat_lspd_product_type using (product_type_id)
left join ef_dat_lspd_model_relationship on (machine_type_model_id_from = machine_type_model_id) 
where (discontinue_date is null or discontinue_date > sysdate) and
(announce_date is null or announce_date <= sysdate)
and (machine_type_model_id in (select machine_type_model_id from ef_dat_lspd_model_parts)
or not machine_type_model_id_to is null) order by machine_type_model_id
```

Below is the unchanged query which I am supposed to work on.

```
select  country_isocode as country,
language_isocode as language,


machine_type_model_id,
product_type_name product_type,machine_type_model_id_to,
image_url
from ef_dat_lspd_machine_type_model cross join ef_dim_lspd_country_language 
left join ef_dat_lspd_model_country using (machine_type_model_id, country_isocode) 
join ef_dat_lspd_product_type using (product_type_id) 
left join ef_dat_lspd_model_relationship on (machine_type_model_id_from =    machine_type_model_id)
where (discontinue_date is null or discontinue_date > sysdate) and
(announce_date is null or announce_date <= sysdate) and
(machine_type_model_id in (select machine_type_model_id from ef_dat_lspd_model_parts) or >not machine_type_model_id_to is null)
order by machine_type_model_id
```

Now in the ef_dat_app_ef_link table there is a link with images,countrycode and languagecode and a revenueid and the other is ef_dat_lspd_machine_type_model which contains the image links and a few more columns. What I am trying to do is, create a query which shall replace pull up images from the ef_dat_app_ef_link table where the revenue id in this table is equal to the revenue id in the other table. A lot of columns come up when a table is searched by the revenue id, thats why i want to pull up a row which has language as 'en' and country as 'US' or 'CA'.

I have added an inner join statement to the same effect but it is consistently throwing a ORA00905 error for a missing keyword.

I have italicized the changes I have made. Sorry for such a bad representation of the code. I couldn't make head or tail of how to make it look better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a WHERE clause smack dab in the middle of the existing query. You can't have more than one WHERE clause in a query, and you also can't place it in the middle of your table joins.

[image: illustrated issue]

Merge the WHERE clause you added to the pre-existing one (indicated by the green arrow in the snapshot).

Comment: Sir, So this part is wrong?    inner join ef_dat_app_ef_link on  (ef_dat_lspd_machine_type_model.lpmd_revenue_pid = ef_dat_app_ef_link.ef_product_revenue_pid)
where (ef_dat_app_ef_link.country_isocode='US' or ef_dat_app_ef_link.country_isocode='CA') and ef_dat_app_ef_link.language_isocode='en'  

How do I improve on this?
Thanks again sir.

Comment: Yea, I typing from phone else I would have added a code example, but your new where clause, you need to merge it with the existing where clause. You can't have multiple where clauses in a SQL statement and it also can't be in the middle of your table selections (like it is now)

Comment: Oh ok. But sir, cant I have multiple join statements with where clauses? Should i enclose the same statement in a bracket and move on from there? Because as you see from the query, it is not physically possible to do what am trying to do. Thanks again Sir.

Comment: Thank you so very much sir. I am new to SQL and I have been able to successfully run the above statement. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix the structure like that you have to do it like

```
select *
from t
join t1
join t2
where 
and
or
order by
```

you can't do this

```
select *
from t
join t2
where
order 
join 
where
order
```

try

```
select country_isocode as country,
language_isocode as language, model_number,
machine_type_model_name model_name,machine_type_group_id,    
machine_type_model_id, product_type_name product_type,
machine_type_model_id_to,filenet_link 
from ef_dat_lspd_machine_type_model
cross join ef_dim_lspd_country_language
left join ef_dat_lspd_model_country 
using (machine_type_model_id, country_isocode)
inner join ef_dat_app_ef_link on  (ef_dat_lspd_machine_type_model.lpmd_revenue_pid = ef_dat_app_ef_link.ef_product_revenue_pid)
join ef_dat_lspd_product_type using (product_type_id)
left join ef_dat_lspd_model_relationship on (machine_type_model_id_from = machine_type_model_id) 
where (ef_dat_app_ef_link.country_isocode='US' or ef_dat_app_ef_link.country_isocode='CA') and ef_dat_app_ef_link.language_isocode='en'
and (discontinue_date is null or discontinue_date > sysdate) and
(announce_date is null or announce_date <= sysdate)
and (machine_type_model_id in (select machine_type_model_id from ef_dat_lspd_model_parts)
or not machine_type_model_id_to is null) order by machine_type_model_id
```

Comment: But you see I am getting that missing keyword in the 10th line. The    inner join ef_dat_app_ef_link which i had added. The second unchanged query runs fine without any issues.